# How to speed up loading images from Filepicker?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, filepicker.io, filepicker

W are using Filepicker as a upload tool for users' images. The app is written in Rails, so we are displaying images like this:

```
= filepicker_image_tag @user.filepicker_url
```

But this approach is kinda slow. We are using as a storage the default Filepicker at the moment and trying to test now Amazon S3 (but I'm kinda worrying it's gonna be the same as the images are loaded from 3rd server).
The another issue we have is that we resize the originally uploaded images on the fly, so when someone will upload an image 2000x1500px, we will resize it in the app with using CSS on the needed proportions. So this is probably the biggest thing what slowing it down.
I am working on resizing all images at the moment.

I am convinced this will has some impact, however, what are another tips/ways to speed up loading images from Filepicker?

Answer (score 1):

To quickly speed up your application you can use a CDN like CloudFront.
Here is the documentation on how to integrate it with Filepicker.io:

https://developers.inkfilepicker.com/docs/cdn/

Also, you can covert images on the fly with FilePicker.io, which would then be cached by the CDN and be served from there.

https://developers.inkfilepicker.com/docs/web/#convert